# Using Drupal 7 Computed Field to provide Date Field Token

Tags: drupal-7, computed-field

In Drupal 7, I have an Event content type. When saved, I want it's URL to be **/calendar/day/{yyyy-mm-dd}/{title}**, where **{yyyy-mm-dd}** is based on `field_event_date`. The [Token module](http://drupalmodules.com/module/token) can do this for create & change date fields, but not for a custom field I created, called field_event_date. So, to compensate, I want to create a [computed field](http://drupalmodules.com/module/computed-field) called `field_event_date_Ymd`, which stores the **yyyy-mm-dd** format from `field_event_date`, so that I can reference it in the URL pattern.

I'm not a PHP programmer, so can someone help me with the code for this? Is it something like this?

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $field_event_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $field_event_date->format('Y-m-d');
```